# 18.04 Searching for file names is incredibly slow

Tags: 18.04

If I remove the search text and replace it immediately the search works in seconds. So I have do all searches twice. I have got used to this over the last year.
Giving an example, I use what appears to be the Files program, and search the Home folder. I type the word "cyclone" and press enter. It says "searching" and get no results for many minutes. I delete the word "cyclone" and replace it immediately. In seconds I get dozens of results. This almost always happens, that I have to do all searches twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, this is buggy behaviour in the file manager of Ubuntu 18.04. Search behaviour kept improving in more recent versions of Files. Actually, Ubuntu 18.04 is using a version that is older than its Gnome Shell version to keep the desktop icons functional - in the version of files that actually belongs to the Gnome Shell version of Ubuntu 18.04, support for desktop icons was already removed.

It is probably quite difficult for an 'ordinary user' to seamlessly replace the Files version of the distribution with a more recent version. Thus, you may need to 'sweat out' this poor version until the next Ubuntu LTS will come out, which is next spring (April 2020). If this issue bothers you (it did greatly bother me), then you may consider upgrading to the most recent interim release of Ubuntu, Ubuntu 19.10, which features a version of Gnome Shell that has greatly improved.